# Calculate the distance between two digital lat/long points

Tags: trigonometry

Let's say I have:

`41.115562000000, -74.047621000000`

and

`41.095640000000, -74.011084000000`

Is there a formula to calcuate the distance between these two points?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert the distance between two lat/long points into feet/meters?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29157/how-do-i-convert-the-distance-between-two-lat-long-points-into-feet-meters)

Comment: See: [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47711/literature-of-geographic-to-cartesian-conversion). There are a number of previous questions and answers available using tag "geometry" and topic "latitude, longitude"...

Comment: thanks guys -- sorry for the dups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what degree of accuracy you are looking for. This article on geographical distance from wikipedia should be useful http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_distance. Since the points are so close together and not near a pole, you could safely use the spherical earth projected to a plane.